# C# - Setting url of a Hyperlink control in a Gridview TemplateField column

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, gridview, templatefield

I have a gridview that has a column that has a Hyperlink control as wellas a LinkButton control. As such:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Actions">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="linkEdit" runat="server"  NavigateUrl="~/shipment.aspx">Edit</asp:HyperLink> | 
        <asp:LinkButton ID="linkSend" runat="server">Send</asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle Width="76" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Each row will have an "Actions" column that looks like this: **Edit | Send**

How do I set the NavigateUrl property of the Hyperlink in each row to include a value from the first column of the row?

**Example: NavigateUrl="~/shipment.aspx?edit=VALUE_FROM_COLUMN_0_OF CURRENT_ROW"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="linkEdit" runat="server"  
     NavigateUrl='<%# "~/shipment.aspx?edit=" + Eval("IdField")" %>' >Edit</asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: I tried that already all I get is error: Compiler Error Message: CS1010: Newline in constant

Comment: Figured it out:

NavigateUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "shipment_id", "~/shipment.aspx?edit={0}") %>'

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot:

```
asp:HyperLink ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("~/shipment.aspx?edit={0}", Eval("SomeID")) %>' ...>
```